# When starting an intent chooser for email, how to get rid of the suggested receivers?

Tags: android, android-intent-chooser

[image]

To start an intent chooser for email, I followed the document.https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Email

I used ACTION_SENDTO as action.

The result is shown in the screenshot. Besides the possible apps to open this, there are also some suggested contacts (most frequent contacts I guess) on the first row. If clicking on it, both that address and the address I clicked on the first place will be pre-filled.

Is there a way to get rid of them and showing only the apps?

Comment: This is a normal behavior for `ACTION_SEND`  UI. You can simply ignore and pick your chooser. unless you want to directly goto email, then ask that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ACTION_SENDTO, there is no way to get rid of the suggested contacts.